# Incorrect SupplyParameterFromQuery values in Maui Blazor Hybrid in .NET 8

Tags: blazor, maui, maui-blazor

Since moving my MAUI Blazor Hybrid application to .NET 8, I noticed strange behaviour with parameters, that I do not see in .NET 7 Blazor Hybrid, or .NET 8 Blazor server, for example.

In my app I pass values around using a query parameter. In a page that is picked up with a `SupplyParameterFromQuery` attribute. Normally, the parameter value is correct when referencing it in `OnInitialized`. However, when navigating to the second page, in `OnInitialized` it gets the parameter that was passed to the first page!

I test this as follows in a standard `MauiBlazorHybid` template:

`Home.razor`:

```
@page "/"

<a href="/testpage1?cachekey=keyA">testpage1?cachekey=keyA</a>
```

`Testpage1.razor`:

```
@page "/testpage1"

<h3>testpage1</h3>

<p>cachekey when initializing: @CacheKeyWhenInitializing</p>
<p>cachekey final: @CacheKey</p>
<p>onparametersset called: @OnparametersSetCount</p>

<a href="/testpage2?cachekey=keyB">testpage2?cachekey=keyB</a>

@code {
    [Parameter, SupplyParameterFromQuery(Name = "cachekey")]
    public string CacheKey { get; set; }

    string CacheKeyWhenInitializing = "";
    int OnparametersSetCount = 0;

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        CacheKeyWhenInitializing = CacheKey;
    }

    protected override void OnParametersSet()
    {
        OnparametersSetCount++;
    }
}
```

`TestPage2.razor`:

```
@page "/testpage2"

<h3>testpage2</h3>

<p>cachekey when initializing: @CacheKeyWhenInitializing</p>
<p>cachekey final: @CacheKey</p>
<p>onparametersset called: @OnparametersSetCount</p>

@code {
    [Parameter, SupplyParameterFromQuery(Name = "cachekey")]
    public string CacheKey { get; set; }

    string CacheKeyWhenInitializing = "";
    int OnparametersSetCount = 0;

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        CacheKeyWhenInitializing = CacheKey;
    }

    protected override void OnParametersSet()
    {
        OnparametersSetCount++;
    }
}
```

The link in the homepage opens testpage1 with keyA as parameter value:

[image]

After clicking, `KeyA` is picked up fine in `Oninitialized` in `TestPage1`:

[image]

The link in `TestPage1` navigates to `TestPage2`, with parameter value `keyB`. The result after clicking:

[image]

This goes wrong. Instead of `keyB`, `TestPage2` gets `keyA`!

You also see that `OnParameterSet` is called twice now. Probably first for `keyA` and then for `keyB`.

As said I tested it in .NET 8 Blazor server as well, where it works normal. `TestPage2` gets `keyB` right away, with only one call to `OnParameterSet`.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Which platform are you running this project on? Please provide your vs version so that I can reproduce your problem.

Comment: Thanks. I am use the latest releases, VS 17.8.3, MAUI Blazor Hybrid (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebView.Maui 8.0.3).

Comment: if you need my repo, let me know.

Comment: I tested it on the 3 platforms: android device, ios simulator and windows. The incorrect behaviour is consistent on all tested platforms.

Answer (score 0):

The `OnInitialized` method is called when a component is initialized, not when it receives new parameters. If you put `CacheKeyWhenInitializing = CacheKey;` inside the `OnInitialized` method, it will only take effect during the initial initialization of the component.

Depending on your requirements, you can choose to set `CacheKeyWhenInitializing` in the `OnParametersSet` method, like the following code:

```
Protected override void OnParametersSet()
{
    OnparametersSetCount++;
    CacheKeyWhenInitializing = CacheKey;
}
```

Comment: I understand that new parameters will not be visible in OnInitialized. But that is not the case here, there are no _new_ parameters to an already inititalized component. TestPage1 is called once, and then TestPage2 is called once. 

The point is that TestPage2 gets a parameter value that was set to TestPage1, which is strange and confusing.